# import my website's events to facebook timeline events using php

Tags: php, facebook

I am developing websites related to events management.is there any facility in facebook,for importing my website's events into facebook timeline through php?

Comment: you can add events to facebook feed

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is... The Facebook API.

Read up on the [Facebook Developers website](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/).

Steps to take, without going into further detail:

1. Create a FB App
2. Get an App ID/API Key, App Secret and Access Token. (Although, the offline_access permission is being removed, so make sure you read up on that as well.)
3. Download the PHP SDK (You can find it under 'SDK Reference'.)
4. Use the appropriate functions in the PHP SDK to create posts, events, ... on your Facebook page. The first time you do that, Facebook should pop up a window asking you to accept the rights of the app to put something on your profile.

Comment: I dont want to create events on facebook page.I want to import already created events on my site to the facebook timeline...

Comment: You can, you just have to give the correct information to the API.

Comment: but can i post future events to FB timeline?